Why is my inverse kinematics script not working unity2d
I really dont know why it is not working
for contexts joint[2] is the end effector
public class FeetMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject[] Joints;
    public List<float> Distances;
    public float[] Lenghts;
    public Transform ToReach;
    [Space(15)]
    public float DistanceReachable;
    public Vector2 DistanceFromBase;


    void Update()
    {
        DistanceFromBase = Joints[0].transform.position - ToReach.transform.position;
        int i = 0;
        Distances.Clear();
        foreach (var j in Joints)
        {
            if (i > 0 && i != Distances.Count)
            {
                Distances.Add((Joints[i].transform.position - Joints[i - 1].transform.position).magnitude);
            }
            else if (i == 1)
            {
                Distances.Add((Joints[i].transform.position).magnitude);
            }
            else if (i != 0 && i == Distances.Count)
            {
                Distances.Add((Joints[i].transform.position - ToReach.transform.position).magnitude);
            }
            i++;
        }
        DistanceReachable = Distances.Sum();
        if (DistanceFromBase.magnitude > DistanceReachable)
        {
            Debug.Log("Outside of possible reach,Distance:" + DistanceFromBase.magnitude + " Press Y to move it closer");

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Y))
            {
                // Calculate the maximum distance to move
                float maxDistanceToMove = Mathf.Min(DistanceFromBase.magnitude - DistanceReachable, 1000);

                // Move ToReach closer
                ToReach.position = ToReach.position + (Vector3)(DistanceFromBase.normalized) * maxDistanceToMove;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Inside of possible reach,Distance:" + DistanceFromBase.magnitude + " Reach surplus: " + (DistanceReachable - DistanceFromBase.magnitude));
        }
        Joints[0].transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0,Mathf.Atan2(DistanceFromBase.y,DistanceFromBase.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + 90);
        Vector2 FromFirstToSecond = Joints[1].transform.position - Joints[0].transform.position;
        Joints[1].transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Mathf.Atan2(FromFirstToSecond.y, FromFirstToSecond.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90);
        Vector2 endEffectorPosition = CalculateEndEffectorPosition();

        // Move the end effector to the calculated position
        Joints[2].transform.position = endEffectorPosition;
    }
    private Vector2 CalculateEndEffectorPosition()
    {
        // Get the angle of the first joint relative to the horizontal axis
        float firstJointAngle = Mathf.Atan2(DistanceFromBase.y, DistanceFromBase.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + 90;

        // Get the angle of the second joint relative to the first joint
        Vector2 fromFirstToSecond = Joints[1].transform.position - Joints[0].transform.position;
        float secondJointAngle = Mathf.Atan2(fromFirstToSecond.y, fromFirstToSecond.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90;

        // Calculate the position of the end effector based on joint angles
        Vector2 endEffectorPosition = Joints[0].transform.position +
                                      new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(firstJointAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad), Mathf.Sin(firstJointAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad), 0) * Distances[0] +
                                      new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(secondJointAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad), Mathf.Sin(secondJointAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad), 0) * Distances[1];

        return endEffectorPosition;
    }
}



I tried to repair it but i cant make it work the end effector stays in place or flies away and just the hand doesnt work and i know i code wierd cuz im not that good just help me if you can i dont want to know what to optimize and things like that i dont need to know
